# x264 [error]: baseline profile doesn't support 4:2:2

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I can play the video stream from my UVC camera using the following:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video4 ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

Now, I would like to convert the stream to h264, in order to pipe it further (i.e. not necessarily to `autovideosink`). But when I do the following:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video4 ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

I get the error:

```
x264 [error]: baseline profile doesn't support 4:2:2
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the use of 4:2:0 by setting caps between `videoconvert` and `x264enc`, like so:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video4 ! videoconvert ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! x264enc ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

Note: "4:2:2" specifies the "[chroma subsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling)", and there are nice comparisons [here](https://www.rtings.com/tv/learn/chroma-subsampling).

Definition:

> Chroma subsampling is a type of compression that reduces the color information in a signal in favor of luminance data. This reduces bandwidth without significantly affecting picture quality.